# Weird filter result in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following PHP function to filter a MySQL table:

```
  public function buscarModelos($searchWord)
    {
        $returnValue = array();

        $sql = "select * from tb_modelos  where 1";

        if(!empty($searchWord))
        {
            $sql .= " and ( agencia_modelo LIKE ?  )";
              $sql .= " ORDER BY nombre_modelo";

        }

        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if (!$statement)
            throw new Exception($statement->error);

        if(!empty($searchWord))
        {
          $searchWord = '%' ;
          $statement->bind_param("s",  $searchWord );
        }

        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->get_result();

         while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
         {
           $returnValue[] = $myrow;
         }

        return $returnValue;
    }
```

I need to filter for $searchWord, in this case $searchWord = TOU656.

My issue is that the query is not filtering as I want.

[image]

As you can see, there is a row (#34) that has TOU658 as value for key agencia_modelo

I am calling the PHP function from a iOS app and I only want to get the rows that have TOU656 as value for key agencia_model, but row #34 is also received as part from the filter result.

EDIT

string(87) "select * from tb_modelos where 1 and ( agencia_modelo LIKE ? ) ORDER BY nombre_modelo" string(1) "%" {"friends":[{"id_modelo":34,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER 200","agencia_modelo":"TOU658"},{"id_modelo":2,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER 300","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":7,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER NEON","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":16,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER PACIFICA","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":15,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER TOWN & COUNTRY","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":6,"nombre_modelo":"CHRYSLER VISION","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":4,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE ATOS","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":5,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE ATTITUDE","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":32,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE AVENGER","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":13,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE DURANGO","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":14,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE GRAND CARAVAN","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":8,"nombre_modelo":"DODGE JOURNEY","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":25,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT 500","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":26,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT 500 L","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":27,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT 500 X","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":29,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT DUCATO","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":21,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT MOBI","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":23,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT PALIO","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":24,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT PALIO ADVENTURE","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":22,"nombre_modelo":"FIAT UNO","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":11,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP CHEROKEE","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":10,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP COMPASS","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":12,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":9,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP PATRIOT","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":31,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP RENEGADE","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":30,"nombre_modelo":"JEEP WRANGLER","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":18,"nombre_modelo":"RAM 700","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":17,"nombre_modelo":"RAM PICKUP","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":19,"nombre_modelo":"RAM PROMASTER","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"},{"id_modelo":20,"nombre_modelo":"RAM PROMASTER RAPID","agencia_modelo":"TOU656"}]}

Comment: It looks like you're changing `$searchWord` to `%` which will match anything.  `$searchWord = '%' ;`  If you remove that does it work?

Comment: @drew010, thank you, let me try

Comment: If argument `$searchWord` is empty, the query result is not filtering. You make sure `$searchWord` is not empty when you call function?

Comment: @drew010, removing that line of code doesn't work either

Comment: @CalosKao, yes I am sure, the app is not calling the PHP file if there is no value for it

Comment: What does `var_dump($sql, $searchWord);` show if you put that right before `$statement->execute();` ?  You might be looking for `$searchWord = '%' . $searchWord . '%';` to do a wildcard match.  Just note this will require a full table scan and won't take advantage of indexes.

Comment: @drew010, question edited showing var_dump result

Comment: It looks like `$searchWord` is still `%`.  Delete the line `$searchWord = '%';` to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If argument `$searchWord` is not empty, set value `'%'`?

If `agencia_modelo LIKE '%'`, query result is not filtering by column `agencia_modelo`.

```
if(!empty($searchWord))
{
    $searchWord = '%' ; // <--- Here
    $statement->bind_param("s",  $searchWord );
}
```

Comment: It is now as you say, where is the change?

Comment: @mvasco Try to delete `$searchWord = '%' ;`?